# How to loop through pandas dataframe, and conditionally assign values to a row of a variable?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to loop through the 'vol' dataframe, and conditionally check if the sample_date is between certain dates. If it is, assign a value to another column.

Here's the following code I have:

```
vol = pd.DataFrame(data=pd.date_range(start='11/3/2015', end='1/29/2019'))
vol.columns = ['sample_date']
vol['hydraulic_vol'] = np.nan
for i in vol.iterrows():
    if  pd.Timestamp('2015-11-03') <= vol.loc[i,'sample_date'] <= pd.Timestamp('2018-06-07'):
        vol.loc[i,'hydraulic_vol'] = 319779
```

Here's the error I received:
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you would do it properly:

```
cond = (pd.Timestamp('2015-11-03') <= vol.sample_date) & 
       (vol.sample_date <= pd.Timestamp('2018-06-07'))

vol.loc[cond, 'hydraulic_vol'] = 319779
```

Comment: Try `vol.sample_date.between('2015-11-03', '2018-06-07')`. `Datetimes` are smart enough to compare with strings and .between is a bit more readable :D (IMO).

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this would be to use the `np.where` method from the `numpy` module, in combination with the `.between` method.

This method works like this:
`np.where(condition, value if true, value if false)`

**Code example**

```
cond = vol.sample_date.between('2015-11-03', '2018-06-07')
vol['hydraulic_vol'] = np.where(cond, 319779, np.nan)
```

Or you can combine them in one single line of code:

```
vol['hydraulic_vol'] = np.where(vol.sample_date.between('2015-11-03', '2018-06-07'), 319779, np.nan)
```

**Edit**
I see that you're new here, so here's something I had to learn as well coming to python/pandas.

Looping over a dataframe should be your last resort, try to use `vectorized solutions`, in this case `.loc` or `np.where`, these will perform better in terms of speed compared to looping.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this! Shifting paradigm to vectorized way of coding has been a learning curve for me.